# Paypal pending purchase - IPN

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I have an ASP.NET website and my customers can perform purchases on site using Paypal Express Checkout Recurring Payment.

I don't know what happened but my first customer had tried to pay and did the whole process perfectly. However, the purchase process is "Pending".

I have a IPN.aspx page that Paypal knows to send the IPN's to and it all worked fine on Sandbox.

How can I dubeg this (Paypal expects some links that are not localhost) and how can I ask Paypal to send me the payment for approval?

This is very crucial for me as this is the only income I have ever received from Paypal and unfortunately needs it very much.

Any assistance will be great, even if I need to change the whole process.

**EDIT:**

"Recurring" is not relevant as I see now that it happens in regular payments as well

Comment: Where you see the status as pending ? In PayPal account or on your website ?

Comment: In Paypal. and I think the "Recurring" is not relevant as I see now that it happens in regular payments as well

Comment: I had this for my first customer also, but the testing account that I set up showed completed. I'm unsure if it's a problem with the customer account, or really how to handle it, since I can't duplicate it with my own test account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not answering my own question.
What I needed to do is update the IPN address in the PayPal settings, then it sent the PayPal notifications to that address.
The problem was that I didn't wait long enough for the notification to be received as PayPal does not do the recurring purchase immediately after the setting of the purchaser recurring profile, it takes a while (wait up to a day).